# Is there a way to bypass Chrome geolocation dialog in Protractor tests?

Tags: geolocation, protractor, webdriver, location, selenium-chromedriver

I faced this problem, when automating an application with protractor.

Once I open a home page I get geolocation dialog with Block/Allow buttons, which didn't let proceed without selection either option

[image]

It turned out, that this dialog is not an instance of alert, that's why `browser.switchTo().alert().confirm()` didn't work

Passing `'--disable-notifications'` argument to Chrome also didn't solve the problem

Research online didn't give any positive results. How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem is to pass `"prefs": {'profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation': 2}` to `capabilities` object in your protractor.config.js

Below is another option that does pretty much the same thing.

So chrome may take an argument `--user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome` which specifies profile to open chrome with. If profile doesn’t exist at specified directory it creates default one.
Then if you open /tmp/chrome/Default/Preferences you’ll see an object with preferences. You needed to set `default_content_setting_values.geolocation` to `2` (not 1 or 0) to make it NOT prompt that dialog