# Accept alert in protractor is throwing `no such alert` error

Tags: protractor

I am writing an E2E test to accept alert.

It is a chrome dialog. Attaching pic for reference:

**browser alert**

[image: browser alert]

Below is my code:

```
await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);      
await browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
await browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
```

When trying to accept the alert, I get the below error

```
 Failed: no such alert
    (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.27)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628411 (3324f4c8be9ff2f70a05a30ebc72ffb013e1a71e),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
```

Appreciate your suggestions on this.

Comment: It may be the file dialog is not an alert as such. If so, you might want to treat it as a window, switch to it by finding its handle, and then hit the button you want. (but I'm not positive it's a window in that sense, either)

Comment: just try this https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/308

Comment: @JeremyKahan this is a browser alert thrown after an action. However , I tried switching to window handle but still doesn't work.

Comment: @ShabeerSha the solutions mentioned in the link doesn't work for me. The solution talks about refreshing the page and I dont want to refresh the browser because the changes I made will be lost if I refresh the browser.

Comment: I am on angular 7 with protractor version 5.4.2

Comment: First try to go through this page https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ and try different arguments to see if it helps. You need to find an option for Chrome NOT ask for confirmation. If no luck, look at the solution to this problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55731421/is-there-a-way-to-bypass-chrome-geolocation-dialog-in-protractor-tests/55731422#55731422 , you may have the same approach

Comment: I'm sorry my idea did not help.

Answer (score 0):

First try to pass this to your `capabilities` in conf.js

```
capabilities: {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "chromeOptions": {
            "args": ["incognito", "--window-size=1920,1080", "disable-extensions", "start-maximized", "--test-type=browser"],
            "prefs": {
                "download": {
                    "prompt_for_download": false,
                    "directory_upgrade": true,
                    "default_directory": path.join(process.cwd(), "tmp/downloads")
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

I'm almost sure it'll help, if not take a look at my comment above^