# Accept location permission request in chrome using protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, geolocation, protractor, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

I am testing one of the google website using protractor, when I run my test script using UI mode it works fine. but, when I run my script in headless mode it automatically block the location and so I am not able to proceed ahead as I'm getting "user denied the request for geolocation. Please change the location setting" this error popup aleart.

How do I make protractor turns on geolocation automatically in headless too ?

I have tried following solutions
1. https://medium.com/@petertc/pro-tips-for-selenium-setup-1855a11f88f8
2. profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": with value 0,1,2 also tried values.geolocation too

Comment: does that answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55731421/is-there-a-way-to-bypass-chrome-geolocation-dialog-in-protractor-tests/55731422#55731422

Comment: Already tried that solution not working in headless mode.. Also changed chrome setting still not working.